# Is there someway to respawn an NPC in roblox studio?

Tags: lua, roblox

So, I'm coding this fighting game in roblox studio. Now I have made an NPC, but I want to script it to be able to respawn a few seconds after dead, but I don't know how to check if an NPC is dead or how to respawn one and make it join its body parts again.

Thank you, and I hope you can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the health of the NPC from the `Health` property of its `Humanoid` in order to see if it's still alive, or if it's dead.

```
game.workspace.<NPC>.Humanoid.Health
```

Now in order to check if it's dead, you can do:

```
if game.workspace.<NPC>.Humanoid.Health <= 0 then
--NPC is dead; respawn
end
```

In order to 'respawn' the NPC, duplicate the NPC (in `workspace`) and place the copy in `ReplicatedStorage`. Now whenever the NPC died, you can replace it with a new one by `cloning` the one in `ReplicatedStorage` to `workspace`:

```
 if game.workspace.<NPC>.Humanoid.Health <= 0 then
    wait(2) -- If you want to wait before the NPC respwns, change '2' for the amount of seconds you want to wait
    game.ReplicatedStorage.<NPC>:Clone().Parent = game.workspace
 end
```

Finally, wrap this all in a `while` loop so it can continuously check the health of the NPCs.

```
while wait() do
  if game.workspace.<NPC>.Humanoid.Health <= 0 then
      wait(2) -- If you want to wait before the NPC respwns, change '2' for the amount of seconds you want to wait
      game.ReplicatedStorage.<NPC>:Clone().Parent = game.workspace
  end
end
```

Comment: This is a good answer! As an optimization, rather than using a while-loop to check the NPC's health, after you spawn the NPC you can listen to the [Humanoid.Died event](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/event/Humanoid/Died).  Then in the event handler, you can wait for a little bit and then spawn a new NPC.